# Dynamically exclude a key from type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

To understand my question, first let me explain what I'm trying to achieve.

I wrote the following `groupBy` function:

```
const groupBy = <T extends Record<keyof T, unknown>>(arr: T[], key: keyof T) => {
    return arr.reduce((prev, { [key]: k, ...rest }) => {
        if (!prev[k]) prev[k] = [] as Omit<T, keyof T>[];
        prev[k].push(rest);

        return prev;
    }, {} as Record<keyof T, Omit<T, keyof T>[]>);
};
```

Now, let's say I have the following interface:

```
type MyType = {
   city: number,
   name: string
}
```

and the following list:

```
const L: MyType[] = [
   {
      city: 1,
      name: "name1"
   },
   {
      city: 1,
      name: "name2"
   },
   {
      city: 2,
      name: "name3"
   },
   {
      city: 2,
      name: "name4"
   }
]
```

When I call the function like this:

```
const grouped = groupBy(L, "city")
```

I want the the type of `grouped` to be as follows:

```
Record<number, Omit<MyType, "city">[]>
```

I.e., the passed key to the `groupBy` function should be omitted from the array items' type.

How can I achieve this? is it achievable at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. Since we need to ensure that the type of the key (`"city"`) is both a key of the object *and* a `PropertyKey` (so we can use it as the key of a `Record`), I think we have to use a conditional type like this:

```typescript
type GroupByResult<ObjectType, KeyType extends keyof ObjectType> =
    ObjectType[KeyType] extends PropertyKey
    ? Record<ObjectType[KeyType], Omit<ObjectType, KeyType>[]>
    : never;
```

Then the types on the function are:

```typescript
export const groupBy = <ObjectType, KeyType extends keyof ObjectType>(
    arr: ObjectType[],
    key: KeyType
): GroupByResult<ObjectType, KeyType> => {
    // ...
};

// ...
const grouped = groupBy(L, "city")
//    ^? −− const grouped: Record<number, Omit<MyType, "city">[]>
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gTgewK5gEIgEoQM5IDbAA8A8gEYBWEAxsACrgQA0UA0hCPZFBAB7AQA7ACbYoAa3YIAZlDKUanCAD4oAXgBQULbIrU6DANpsODALrc+gkVAAKiSHFDHN2gPxQsVBHCEldCw2NFU2ZiAFsASyI5PUVmIIYlA1MlFy0ALigBCAA3CDgAbnV1XjBvYCgvAWwKgHNEFHQ1KD95fUh49kULfmFRCRBpHTbFJQAKNKgAQzg4TJiAyGTGSYHMhMh1AEpM+GQ0TBx8aP92plYuxLUVAG9JuAhgJDgBLPw8adEpgRBP2AaDlhcARWrEGJ0TJAlEUAL5FdSgLgAWUh0FUUDu2kqURAmQESDCpHyRSxAimYQgmRqcAiAlqsPhVRqUAAMpkUYpks0DJNMVjtFQcZkAIwrfnaMkUzIAIklEGF0rF2hhSq0fPFgtAItV-LlMrlACZFZMVbzJljNbioAadaTyZSoLL7QBmY1Y01Y9X8y2ZG3miX2-X2gAsbuVK1MjIQ1TqAIgQma9X26DGLOY0st0q2RQA9DmsQA9VzqIA)

---

Note: There are type errors in the `reduce` call. I haven't tried to address those as I think your question is about the return type. Let me know if you also need help with those (I suspect you'll always need some type assertion(s) in the implementaton, but I could be wrong).

But I did notice an error in the implementation: You're using `key` where you should be using `k` when indexing into `prev`, the body of the `reduce` callback should be:

```
if (!prev[k]) prev[k] = [];
prev[k].push(rest);
return prev;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gTgewK5gEIgEoQM5IDbAA8A8gEYBWEAxsACrgQA0UA0hCPZFBAB7AQA7ACbYoAa3YIAZlDKUanCAD4oAXgBQULbIrU6DANpsODALrc+gkVAAKiSHFDHN2gPxQsVBHCEldCw2NFU2ZiAFsASyI5PUVmIIYlA1MlFy0ALigBCAA3CDgAbnV1AHoAKl4wb2AykqgvAWxgKABzRBR0NSg-eX1IePZFC35hUQkQaR1exSUACjSoAEM4OEyYgMhkxgXxzITIdQBKTPhkNEwcfGj-PqZWQcS1FQBvBbgIYCQ4ASWVgDp3kIkFQILNZmB3jlmM8oAZxqZMmJmH8Ue8mlAAL6HJ5QV7afFQEp1MokqAAAzEZOYAgQzQp7DJUAiP2AAAtoKQIHgEAB3Bb4iIyWYAQghuThpmxYpyEq6ySKBO00olfzASGwrNmaOAhwViqg70+3yg0r1Wgx0IxS1EiwEIGxi1Epw6F1wBB6sQYAxMkCURQxRXUoC4AFkfdBVLiFlQoiBMgIkGFOYUFgJFmEIJkmnBmS1-YGGuiADKZMOKZJyhZ4-Ux0CZACM231WXTmagACI0xn6+2m9oLVX+dpa3GoI2h1ou23O62AEy9hYD-HVxUjzKzvuKqeZGcZgDMC-xS+0K4Ja6gG4nLYzO6nABZD-3tqYCwhGs02mcIEIup+XbMi2YdsR3bXVSjqbQAD1XHUQsEDwCA-m5FpZj-SAhDA9QpG8KBZkLZouQgDMBGaSY0O-Ax60lKN8TghCkIQFDCOI4A-inMCMSAA) bypassing the internal type errors using `any` (which is often good enough for small, self-contained, easily tested functions like `groupBy`).

Comment: Amazing! Just fix the type definition from `Omit<ObjectType, KeyType>` to `Omit<ObjectType, KeyType>[]`, and you can also replace `string | symbol | number` with `PropertyKey`. Also, thanks for letting me know about the logic error! Regarding the type errors in the reduce call - I can just put `any` for now, so the current implementation is good enough as indeed I only care about the return type. BUT, for learning purposes only, if you can also supply typing for the reduce call as well - then that would be great! :)

Comment: @Elyasaf755 - I did the `[]` fix earlier, before the `key`/`k` thing. Good point about `PropertyType`! Re typing the `reduce`, let me think. It'll have to involve at least two type assertions, since we need to start out with a partial. It's probably more typing than one needs... :-)

Comment: @Elyasaf755 - Yeah, I don't think I'm going to be able to strongly type that `reduce` call. When it gets to something that self-contained and testable, that's the one place where I resort to broad type assertions and lots of testing. :-)

Comment: @Elyasaf755 - If you do find a way to do it, ping me to let me know?

Comment: Sure! Will do :)